# Cached dataframe flushed after truncating table

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

Here are the steps:

```
scala> val df = sql("select * from table")
df: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [num: int]

scala> df.cache
res13: df.type = [num: int]

scala> df.collect
res14: Array[org.apache.spark.sql.Row] = Array([10], [10])

scala> df
res15: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [num: int]

scala> df.show
+---+
|num|
+---+
| 10|
| 10|
+---+


scala> sql("truncate table table")
res17: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = []

scala> df.show
+---+
|num|
+---+
+---+
```

My question is why the df is flushed? My expectation is that it should be cached in the memory and truncate shouldn't erase the data.

Any idea will be much appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `truncate table` command removes the cached data then uncaches and empties the table. [HERE](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/sql/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/execution/command/tables.scala#L426) is the source for `truncate`. If you follow that link to the source code for `TruncateTableCommand`, at the bottom of the case class you'll see the following for how the cache and table are handled when a table is truncated:

```
// After deleting the data, invalidate the table to make sure we don't keep around a stale
// file relation in the metastore cache.
spark.sessionState.refreshTable(tableName.unquotedString)
// Also try to drop the contents of the table from the columnar cache
try {
  spark.sharedState.cacheManager.uncacheQuery(spark.table(table.identifier))
} catch {
  case NonFatal(e) =>
    log.warn(s"Exception when attempting to uncache table $tableIdentWithDB", e)
}

if (table.stats.nonEmpty) {
  // empty table after truncation
  val newStats = CatalogStatistics(sizeInBytes = 0, rowCount = Some(0))
  catalog.alterTableStats(tableName, Some(newStats))
}
Seq.empty[Row]
```

Answer (score 0):

You should never depend on `cache` for correctness. Spark `cache` is performance optimization, and even with the most defensive `StorageLevel` (`MEMORY_AND_DISK_SER_2`) is not guaranteed to preserve data in case of worker failure, executor decommissioning or insufficient resources.

Code similar to the one used in your question might work in some conditions, but don't assume it is guaranteed or deterministic behavior.